# ¿Cuándo se usa el plural en números con decimales?

Tags: gramática, plurales, números

Cuando se usan decimales, usando por ejemplo la palabra "galón", es claro el decir:

- un galón
- dos galones

¿Pero cómo se dice si tengo, por ejemplo, 1.3?

- uno punto tres galón, o
- uno punto tres galones

También está el caso cuando tengo menos de la unidad, por ejemplo, 0.3:

- cero punto tres galón, o
- cero punto tres galones

Personalmente me suena mejor usar el plural pero no se si aún así, en cuanto a las reglas, la forma correcta sea el singular.

Comment: Creo que español es igual que inglés en este aspecto:  Uno es singular, todos los números demás son plurales, incluso cero.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=rqV8h362gD62vc21qB) recoge la siguiente información al respecto:

> por su significado, el cardinal uno solo se refiere a sustantivos
>   singulares: Tengo solo un abrigo; Este mes solo me han puesto una
>   multa; los demás cardinales, puesto que indican siempre cantidad
>   superior a la unidad, solo se refieren a sustantivos plurales:
>   Necesito que me prestes mil doscientos euros; Este mes ya llevo tres
>   multas. El cardinal cero constituye un caso especial, pues aunque
>   expresa ausencia de cantidad, se antepone siempre, como adjetivo, a
>   sustantivos plurales: «De regreso a París, me encontré con [...] cero
>   pesos en la cuenta bancaria» (Jodorowsky Danza [Chile 2001]).

Por lo tanto, para el ejemplo que mencionas, lo correcto es utilizar el plural:

> 1.3 galones
>
> 0.3 galones

Comment: No había pensado en el caso del cero pero es cierto